# SO_RCVTIMEO does not work in VPN env

Tags: linux, network-programming

I have a very simple socket server/client application which access each other 
heartbeat every 30 secs through vpn connection , 
while vpn suddenly broken which should cause  socket 
client recv return -1 , but in vpn case , blocking recv won't  return -1 immediately , I don't know why is that , after several mins or so then 
recv return -1) , so I try to use SO_RCVTIMEO as the following :

```
struct timeval tout ;
tout.tv_sec = 35 ;
tout.tv_usec = 0 ;
int setRcvTimeO = 0 ;
setRcvTimeO = setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tout, sizeof(tout)) ;
while( 1 ){
    int nread = 0  ;
    char strdata[1024]={0},strtmp[32]={0} ;
    if ( (nread = readnx(fd,strtmp,20)) <=  0){  
        close(fd) ;
        if( doConnectServer() ){
            doLoginServer() ;
        }
        sleep(3) ;
        continue ;
    }
    doSomeThing(strtmp) ;
} //while
```

As you can see , I try to reconnect to server after 35 secs fail to receive any 
data , this work in LAN , but in vpn envronment , it still failed to do so , 
the recv still won't return -1 after 35 secs .

The Linux kernel failed to know fd through vpn connection is broken cause this problem , is there anything I can do that I can reconnect server while vpn 
suddently broken ?!

Edit :

```
ssize_t readnx(int fd, void *buffer, size_t n)
{
    ssize_t numRead;                    /* # of bytes fetched by last read() */
    size_t totRead;                     /* Total # of bytes read so far */
    char *buf;

    buf = (char*) buffer;               /* No pointer arithmetic on "void *" */
    for (totRead = 0; totRead < n; ) {
        numRead = recv(fd, buf, n - totRead,MSG_NOSIGNAL);

        if (numRead == 0)               /* EOF */
            return totRead;             /* May be 0 if this is first read() */
        if (numRead == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;               /* Interrupted --> restart read() */
            else
                return -1;              /* Some other error */
        }
        totRead += numRead;
        buf += numRead;
    }
    return totRead;                     /* Must be 'n' bytes if we get here */
}
```

Comment: What is `readnx()`?

Comment: @EJP  , please see the edit , thanks .

Comment: Is the connection using UDP or TCP?

Comment: Also it does not look like you are checking to see if `setsocketopts` is returning an error (IE:` if (setRcvTimeO == -1){ perror("setsockopt(SO_RCVTIMEO) failed"); exit(1);}`

Comment: thanks , I do the check , setsocketopt return 0 , it work while not in VPN, but while in vpn env ,  if vpn suddenly broken and back to normal , this SO_RECVTIMEO won't work , look like recv won't return -1 in this case.